# Importing information into PHPspreadsheets from webhook

Tags: php

Could anyone help me how would I import data from a web hook and place it into a certain cells.

I.E name, number, address

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this question? What code have you tried, and what issues are you encountering?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ This website is more about correcting code that has already been written and which has issues you're seeking help with _ Usually the code is included in the post so that SO contributors can read through it _ Please take a moment to visit the Help Center and specifically the section on 'Asking' for more details >>> stackoverflow.com/help/asking